# Standard User with "Modify Metadata" fails to create active Picklist Value

Tags: metadata-api, permissions, security

What is failing here perfectly works for a **SysAdmin** user. I have a **StandardUser** with a permission set which grants him `ModifyMetadata` and calling this code creates the Picklist Value but leaves it inactive:

```
public without sharing class MyClass {

    @Future(Callout=true)
    private static void updateValueSet(Set<String> newTopics, String fieldName) {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort mdapi = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        mdapi.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        mdapi.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

        MetadataService.CustomField fieldMdApi = (MetadataService.CustomField)
                                        mdapi.readMetadata('CustomField', new String[] { fieldName }).getRecords()[0];

        for(String missing : newTopics) {
            MetadataService.CustomValue value = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
            value.fullName = missing;
            value.default_x = false ;
            value.isActive = true;

            fieldMdApi.valueSet.valueSetDefinition.value.add(value);
        }

        mdapi.updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{ fieldMdApi });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Have you tried to use metadata api to deploy same field (with picklist values as a zip file and ant/workbench) using user with Standard Profile?

Comment: @kurunve no and that not the point. The field already exists and just need new active values

Comment: Had a very similar issue. Have you tried to set the „modify all data“ system permission set? I was not very happy to set it but it worked

Comment: To be honest I don't want to give this perm to standard users